# Image equalisation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image. I would like to equalize histogram using `histeq`. But, I want only certain portion of the image be equalized and the rest part be displayed as it is. I could display the whole image and equalized image in two different plots but I want them to be in the same image such that certain portion of the image is different.

```
figure
imshow(a)
figure
b = a(1:100, 1:100);
b = histeq(b)
imshow(b)
```

Now how do I merge both these figures into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the region to be equalized `a(1:100, 1:100)`?

If so, just set `a(1:100, 1:100) = b`.